# How do I tell if exposed ethernet cable is plenum grade?

Tags: ethernet

I've found a series of ethernet cables running through various exposed* areas in my house and I'm wondering how to tell if they are plenum grade.

*exposed areas are running through duct work and along the base board from the duct vent.

Answer (score 7):

if i am getting you properly other wise tell me

**Look for CMP(means Communications Plenum Cable) ,CL3P(Shielded Multi-Conductor Plenum Security Cable) , or CL2P(Class 2 plenum cable
) marked on the cable.**

Plenum cable is covered with a fire proof plastic layer of either a low-smoke polyvinyl chloride (PVC)   or a fluorinated ethylene polymer (FEP).

1. Plenum cable must not burn easily
2. Plenum cable must not emit toxic fumes when exposed to extreme heat

Comment: that's the definition of "plenum" but does not help him determine if a given cable IS plenum or not.

Comment: How do I tell if its PVC or FEP? I'd rather not actually *test whether it burns* ;)

Comment: @hafichuk see updated answer

Answer (score 5):

It may have a "CMP" designation on it.  If it has a "CM" or "CMR" it is not plenum rated.